# Hotkey for double-click highlight?

Tags: highlight, hotkeys, double-click

I'm working in Eclipse and find myself always replacing multiple copies of the same word, but I always have to take my hands off the keyboard and screen to get the mouse, hover over the word, double click to select, and then copy or rewrite the word. Is there any way I can just move the cursor inside the word and hit some hotkey that would highlight it? Seems like this would be a big timesaver.

Or if there's a way to create a hotkey that would be perfect too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether there is a hotkey I'm not certain but I tend to just use alt-left SHIFT alt-right to select a word (on a Mac). On Windows it's possible that ctrl-left SHIFT ctrl-right works.

Comment: Somewhat works. Not as the way I would like it though. Almost as slow as the mouse =(

Comment: This actually isn't that bad as I thought before. Been using it for a while and I find myself using the mouse less and less. Good thing I guess.